# Ansible: set mode of mysql_db dump file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In an Ansible playbook, I am using the mysql_db module to dump the contents of a database.  I want to ensure that the `.sql` file dumped out by mysql_db on the server side has mode `0600`: readable and writable only by owner, not group and certainly not anybody else.

```
- set_fact:
    backupFileNames:
      db: "{{ansible_env.HOME}}/{{siteName}}.sql"

- name: dump the mysql server
  mysql_db:
    state: dump
    name: "{{mysqlBackupDb}}"
    target: "{{backupFileNames.db}}"
    mode: 0600
```

Unfortunately, mysql_db doesn't have a mode parameter: I get `Unsupported parameters for (mysql_db) module: mode`.

**How can I ensure that the `.sql` dump file is created with properly restricted permissions so that my database contents are not available to other users on the server?**

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory with appropriate permissions and save the file into that directory.

Otherwise use `file` module to set the permissions after the above task (but then you have a period of time when the file has inappropriate permissions - from security standpoint it's a risk - think of the connection failing in-between, maybe unlikely, but not impossible).

Comment: You could maybe use the file module to touch the file, creating it with the proper permissions before doing the backup? Eg. state=touch